# ValueError on Lambda

Tags: python, tensorflow, lambda, keras, conv-neural-network

Im creating a segmentation model I'm adding the conv outputs as following.

```
 conv38_1 = Conv2D(filters=NUM_CLASSES, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=(6,6), padding='same', name='fc1_voc12_c0')(relu38_1)
    conv38_2 = Conv2D(filters=NUM_CLASSES, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=(12,12), padding='same', name='fc1_voc12_c1')(relu38_1)
    conv38_3 = Conv2D(filters=NUM_CLASSES, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=(18,18), padding='same', name='fc1_voc12_c2')(relu38_1)
    conv38_4 = Conv2D(filters=NUM_CLASSES, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=(24,24), padding='same', name='fc1_voc12_c3')(relu38_1)

    output   = Add(name='fc1_voc12')([conv38_1, conv38_2, conv38_3, conv38_4])
    output   = Lambda(lambda image: tf.image.resize_images(image, (H,W)))(output)
```

However I'm getting a strange error as follows,

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected lambda_1 to have
>   shape (321, 321, 1) but got array with shape (321, 321, 2)

why is the third shape element is of 2? is there any ways to sort it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (321,321,2) is the shape of your `y_train`.

This means you're trying to predict two classes/channels per image. 
Your model must then output 2 classes as well.

`NUM_CLASSES` must be 2.

Comment: Just "used to it" :)

Comment: I tried to hardcode the NUM_CLASSES as 2 but still I'm getting the same error :(

Comment: Exactly the same?

Comment: Can you post your `model.summary()` and `y_train.shape`?